# String handling in c

Tags: c, string

Here is my code

```
char* a[10];
a[0]="'example'";
char* p;
p=strstr(a[0],"'");
```

I know if strstr can find the `'` it returns a pointer which points to first character which is `'`. I want to take the value between two `'` and save it in `a[1]`. how should I do that?
As a result
`a[1]` is `"example"`.

Comment: `if (p) a[1] = p + 1;` makes a[1] point to just after the first `'`. You need some way to find the next `'` inside *that* string.

Comment: Homework? (blah blah total rubbish waste of my time and everyone elses extra characters for crazy SO developers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the next occurrence of `'` and copy the substring:

```
char* a[10];
a[0]="'example'";
char* p, *q;
p=strstr(a[0],"'");
if (p) {
    q = strstr(p+1, "'");
    if (q) {
        size_t len = (size_t)(q - p);
        char *sub = malloc(len + 2);
        if (!sub) {
            /* Oops */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  /* Something more sensible rather */
        }
        memcpy(sub, p, len+1);
        sub[len+1] = 0;
        a[1] = sub;
     }
     else {
         a[1] = NULL;
     }
}
else {
    a[1] = NULL;
}
```

Note that in this case, it would be better to use `strchr` to find the single character.

Comment: `strncpy()` is a [dangerous function](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html). In this case, since you know exactly how many bytes you want to copy, `memcpy()` would be cleaner.

Comment: Right, `memcpy` is better. Although when you know exactly how many bytes to copy, that is the situation where `strncpy` is safe too.

Answer (score 2):

[`strchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) seems a more appropriate choice that `strstr()`.

Use the result of first `strchr()`, `+ 1`, as the argument to a subsequent `strchr()` and then `malloc()` and `strcpy()` or `sprintf()` into `a[1]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* a[10];
    char* p;

    a[0] = "'example'";

    p = strchr(a[0], '\'');
    if (p)
    {
        char* q = strchr(++p, '\'');
        if (q)
        {
            a[1] = malloc((q - p) + 1);
            if (a[1])
            {
                sprintf(a[1], "%.*s", q - p, p);
                printf("[%s]\n", a[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Storing pointers to string literals and `malloc()` data into the same array seems a dangerous thing to do. You must `free()` dynamically allocated memory, but *only* dynamically allocated memory. The code will need to know what elements in `a` are pointing at dynamically allocated memory, and must be `free()`d, and those that are not.

Initialise `a` to all `NULL`s, so it is known what elements are populated:

```
char* a[10] = { NULL };
```

and calling `free()` on a `NULL` pointer is safe (does nothing).

Comment: What I need is strchr(). Thanks a lot.